# Адресация процессора

Tags: информатика

Хочу разобраться в адресации, а в книгах очень заумно написано, помогите если можите ...
Поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь: **в оперативной памяти, одна ячейка это один байт в этой ячейки есть адрес, если модуль памяти на 4Гб это 4 миллиарда адресов и ячеек то есть 32-битный процессор за один такт может сразу обратится по 4-м миллиардам адресов за данными в ячейках.**
Вопросы:

1. Кто дает адреса ячейкам оперативной памяти и где они хранятся ?
2. 64-х битный процессор имеет просто шину шире по которой может обращаться сразу к 16Эб оперативной памяти и специальные регистры которые вкурсе того что памяти может быть так дохренищя и это все отличия ?

Дайте хорошую литературу по ЭВМ ... Спасибо всем добрым людям :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> в оперативной памяти, одна ячейка это один байт в этой ячейки есть адрес,

да, хотя на некоторых платформах адресовать байты, адреса которых не кратные 4 бывает сложно.

> если модуль памяти на 4Гб это 4 миллиарда адресов и ячеек

да, чуть больше 4 миллиардов однобайтовых ячеек

> то есть 32-битный процессор за один такт может сразу обратится по 4-м миллиардам адресов за данными в ячейках.

далеко не факт. нет гарантии, что за один такт он успеет. Плюс, есть такое дело как кеш - память внутри процессора. Процессор никогда не читает по одному байту, он обычно читает сразу по 16-32 байта. Но это все на современных Intel x86 процессорах. Плюс на 32битных архитектурах есть определенные ограничения и не вся память доступна, а около 3.5 гигабайт.

> Кто дает адреса ячейкам оперативной памяти и где они хранятся ?

никто. Это как правая и левая рука. В процессоре может храниться адрес(а) ячейки, с которой в данный момент работает процессор.  Но сами номера нигде не хранятся. Другой способ понять. Представьте, что на полке лежит 100 книг и Вам нужна 25. Это же не проблема найти? (только знать, с какой стороны считать номера и начальный). Но сами порядковые номера книг ведь нигде не хранятся и не записаны.

Но что бы глубже понимать, придется изучить схемотехнику, как передаются сигналы и кучу слов вида "триггер, строб, и/или логика, мультиплексор". Точно уверенны, что сможете?

> 64-х битный процессор имеет просто шину шире по которой может обращаться сразу к 16Эб оперативной памяти и специальные регистры которые вкурсе того что памяти может быть так `***` и это все отличия ?

да, шина шире. И регистры "шире". 16Эб памяти он не сможет так просто адресовать. Только в мечатх, но 128 Gb точно. Там хитрее адресация.
Также там ещё и команды умеют работать с 64битными данными. И если сильно не углубляться, то да, это все отличия.

А вот с литературой... может на сайте интела почитать? Правда там все на английском.

Comment: Хм

    то есть 32-битный процессор за один такт может сразу обратится по 4-м миллиардам адресов за данными в ячейках.

Нет, конечно. Объём памяти за такт -- ширина шины (или меньше -- зависит от архитектуры).

    Кто дает адреса ячейкам оперативной памяти и где они хранятся ?

Контроллер, схемотехнические решения и т.п.

Comment: @Алина_Климова, к сожалению реальная работы процессора (даже оставаясь в рамках x-86 архитектуры) несколько сложнее, чем это описал @KoVadim.

1. Процессор сам (со своей частотой) к памяти **не обращается**.

2. Между процессором и кэшем обычно находится еще устройство MMU, которое переводит виртуальные адреса (в процессоре) в физические.

3. Процессор работает (через MMU) с кэшем 1-го уровня (обычно делают кэш из 3-х уровней).

4. Время чтения (в тактах) зависит прежде всего от того, есть ли данные в кэше (и на каком уровне).

5. Там еще можно всего много навспоминать, но тут места мало...

Comment: @avp Благодарю вас, если у вас будет время может дадите ссылку где можно об этом почитать, в википедии так всё разбросано и не понятно написано, буду рада любому материалу !!!

Comment: Почему в Википедии разбросано?

Я, конечно, сейчас внимательно не изучал, но IMHO в статье [Кэш процессора](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) как раз то, что надо (только может быть не очень просто...).

--

Вот еще [нашел ссылочку](http://allasm.ru/proc.php). Наверное надо начинать с "Процессор изнутри. Часть 0: Теория".

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо !